# Django loop template tag does not work

Tags: python, html, django

I've just started playing with Django and I can't seem to get the template tags to work at all.

Here's my code:

views.py

```
def bookpage(request):
    query_results = Books.objects.all()
    data = query_results.values()
    data['title']=query_results.values('title')
    data['authors']=query_results.values('authors')
    return render (request,'index.html',data)
```

bookpage.html

```
<div class="resp-tabs-container">
           <tr>
             <th>Header 1</th>
             <th>Header 2</th>
           </tr>
           {% for x in query_results %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{title.x}}</td>
             <td>{{authors.x}}</td>
           </tr>
           {% endfor %}
```

When I run the code, the whole row ie, the one with the tags did not show at all.

Please enlighten me!

Comment: That code couldn't possibly work; in the view, `query_results` is not a dict, you can't set arbitrary keys on it.

Answer (score 2):

**`x`** is the object and **`title`** and **`authors`** are the attributes. You have put them backwards.

```
{% for x in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.title}}</td>
        <td>{{x.authors}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```